# Scalable stl set like container for C++

Tags: c++, containers, on-disk

I need to store large number of integers. There can be
duplicates in the input stream of integers, I just need 
to store distinct amongst them.
I was using stl set initially but It went OutOfMem when
input number of integers went too high.
I am looking for some C++ container library which would
allow me to store numbers with the said requirement possibly
backed by file i.e container should not try to keep all numbers in-mem.
I don't need to store this data persistently, I just need to find
unique values amongst it.

Comment: What's the integer values range?

Comment: I'm too embarrassed to call this an answer, but maybe you could just rebuild your app for 64-bit and run it on a 64-bit system.

Comment: The problem is main mem is not large enough to hold all numbers and we need external-mem-backed set like container.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/); might be what you're looking for.

Edit: I haven't used it myself, but from the docs - you could use `stream::runs_creator` to create sorted runs of your data (however much fits in memory), then `stream::runs_merger` to merge the sorted streams, and finally use `stream::unique` to filter uniques.

Comment: I just looked at stlxxl. At first glance, it does not seem to have anything like stl::set.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need larger than RAM allows you might look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/)

Comment: memcached ? Could you please explain how that can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using DB (maybe [SQLite](http://file://localhost/home/dmitry/opcdcore/doc/html/index.html))? Or it would be too slow?

Comment: That would be too slow i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously at least try a database before concluding it is too slow. All you need is one of the lightweight key-value store ones. In the past I have used Berkeley DB, but here is a [list of other ones](http://nosql-database.org/).